# Listview selectionmode not functioning correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

For some reason if I have a listview that has checkboxes included it will not allow multiple selection using the shift key.

As far as I am aware I am using this correctly:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

Please note I have removed all of the other settings in the code due to it being unneeded in this example.

I have also done Extended.

Comment: Does it allow multiple selection with the Ctrl key?

Comment: Afraid this isn't currently working either.

Comment: Have you tried it in a blank app? I find that's always worth trying. If it works in a blank one, you know it's something else you have in your code that causes this.

Comment: I actually use SelectionMode in various other places that don't contain checkboxes so I am assuming it is these that are messing it up as they are standard listviews apart from that.

Comment: please check  [Multiselect ListView with checkboxes in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2008/02/04/multiselect-listview-with-checkboxes-in-wpf.aspx), not sure this will solve your issue, but hope this help you some way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use keyboard modifiers you need to set SelectionMode="Extended" and then shift+click.
I cannot remember exactly but Multiple mode only works with Ctrl+Click on each item.

I have used that with listbox control, which is stripped down ListView anyway as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

check that you haven't overridden anything in the list view or disabled controls

If you are using the MVVM pattern, make sure the control hasn't blocked selection

[Selection Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx)